# How to disable Learning phase in Tensorflow Java/scala as we do in python tf.keras.backend.learning_phase(0)

Tags: java, scala, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am using lstm model and loading the saved model as below

```
val modelFiles: List[String] = List(
      "saved_model.pb",
      "keras_metadata.pb",
      "variables/variables.data-00000-of-00001",
      "variables/variables.index"
    )
    val modelDir = "/Models/lstm_model_fullname_with_watchlist"
    val tempDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory("lstm").toFile
 val savedModel = SavedModelBundle.load(tempDirectory.getAbsolutePath, "serve")
    new LSTMModel(
      session = savedModel.session()
    )
```

and calling the prediction as below

```
 val input1: Tensor[_] = Tensor.create(embed(name1))
    val input2: Tensor[_] = Tensor.create(embed(name2))
    val result: Tensor[_] = session.runner()
      .fetch("StatefulPartitionedCall:0")
      .feed("serving_default_input_1:0", input1)
      .feed("serving_default_input_2:0", input2)
      .run().get(0)
```

1. I need to check whether learning_phase is enabled or disabled?
2. How to disable learning phase in Scala or Java. I am using scala. but Java reference is also fine, I hope both would be similar.

I came across this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/java/issues/217) by anychance this option itself not available ?

my current version of tensorflow is 1.15.0.

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this conversation this is something controlled by the model. https://github.com/tensorflow/java/issues/465